# react 18 function component's lifecycle in development

Tags: reactjs

1、React 18 dev document has following description:

When Strict Mode is on, in development, React runs setup and cleanup one extra time before the actual setup.

2、I have following simple code

```
const GrandSon = () => {
  console.log('GrandSon')

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('GrandSon mounted')
    return () => {
      console.log('GrandSon unmounted')
    }
  }, [])

  return <div>GrandSon</div>
}

const Son = () => {
  console.log('Son')

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Son mounted')
    return () => {
      console.log('Son unmounted')
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <div>Son</div>
      <GrandSon />
    </>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  console.log('app')

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('app mounted')
    return () => {
      console.log('app unmounted')
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <Son />
    </div>
  )
}
```

3、The console would output:

```
app
app
Son
Son
GrandSon
GrandSon
GrandSon mounted
Son mounted
app mounted
GrandSon unmounted
Son unmounted
app unmounted
GrandSon mounted
Son mounted
app mounted
```

4、The following log output as my expect

```
GrandSon mounted
Son mounted
app mounted
GrandSon unmounted
Son unmounted
app unmounted
GrandSon mounted
Son mounted
app mounted
```

5、But i have question about the beginning part

```
app
app
Son
Son
GrandSon
GrandSon
```

How it happen, please help me!

Comment: The body of a React component may be called multiple times, but at least once for each render. Otherwise it's not tied to the component being mounted or unmounted. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Hoopra Thank you for your response. I am particularly concerned about the order of the log outputs. Based on my understanding, it should be like this:
app
Son
GrandSon
app
Son
GrandSon

Comment: From what I know you can't count on the order of body calls that way, so I wouldn't worry about it. React only orders mount/unmount and hook calls, but not pure javascript function calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you log something outside of the useEffect, it's likely happening during the render phase of the component, whereas the code inside useEffect is executed during the commit phase.

Here's a breakdown of what might be happening:

1-Outside useEffect:

When your component is initially rendered, the code outside useEffect runs during the render phase.
This is why it appears to run before the component is fully mounted.

2-Inside useEffect:

The code inside useEffect runs during the commit phase, after the render phase.
This is where you typically put side effects, such as data fetching, subscriptions, or other operations that should occur after the component is mounted.

3-React Strict Mode:

When you enable React Strict Mode, it performs additional checks and warnings during development to help you catch potential problems.
Strict Mode intentionally double-invokes certain functions, including render methods and effects, to help detect side-effects.
If you're observing that the outside useEffect console log doesn't run in React Strict Mode, it could be due to the double-invocation behavior in Strict Mode.